# HTML odd symbols

Tags: php, html

I have home problem with the HTML symbols in a spanish web page what I am developing. The symbols are like � on my ñ and á, é, í, ó and ú.

I tried:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Also:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

And:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

But nothing works. Thats how the webpage works:

1. I have an index.php which selects throught $_GET the layout.
2. Layouts are saved in .phtml
3. Then I include the selected file.

Everything works fine, except the charset codification, � symbols remain in the page. What could I do for changing it?

EDIT - I have read the solution proposed and gives no solution, I have done all that they are saying before (as I said at the begining), and I have no problems with MySQL codification.

Comment: Short answer: save and read the data in UTF-8. As I can see, you only read the data in UTF-8. Also, if those are static files, they might not be saved UTF-8 with no BOM.

Comment: Sorry, could't understand your answer. What you mean of saving and reading the data in UTF-8?

Comment: I meant the database write and read.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. No, I am talking about pure HTML, I am not getting that data from MySQL.

Comment: Then, as I said before, the problem is file encoding. Use an editor capable of changing encoding, like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and change the encoding in UTF-8 with no BOM.

Comment: Thats my editing app, and UTF-8 with no BOM its the mode I have been using.

Comment: When you paste the text in the editor, the spanish symbols are displayed correctly?